# Standard structure of a C++/CLI program which uses generics?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, generics, c++-cli

I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the direction of some sample code or project that has a C++/CLI class split between a header (.h) and code file (.cpp), which uses generics with its member functions. I am having some trouble compiling, as I am attempting to treat generics, syntactially, the way I would templates in an unmanaged C++ project, and can't seem to find any good examples of generics being used in a split file. And yes, this is my first time trying to build a project in C++/CLI.

Here's my code, if anyone can spot the errors:

**The C++/CLI .dll:**

```
.h:
#ifndef __ManagedCPlusPlus_h__
#define __ManagedCPlusPlus_h__

//#include "CPlusPlusArray.h"

using namespace System;


class CPlusPlusArray;

namespace ManagedCPlusPlusArray {

    generic<typename S2, typename I2>
    public ref class ManagedCPlusPlusArray
    {
        public:
            ManagedCPlusPlusArray(S2 size);
            void SetItem(S2 index, I2 value);
            I2 GetItem(S2 index);
            S2 Size(void);
            virtual ~ManagedCPlusPlusArray(void);
        private:
            CPlusPlusArray* m_cppa;
    };
}

#endif  



.cpp:
// This is the main DLL file.

#include <STDIO.H>  

//#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ManagedCPlusPlusArray.h"
#include "CPlusPlusArray.h"

using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
namespace ManagedCPlusPlusArray
{
    generic<typename S2, typename I2>
    ManagedCPlusPlusArray<S2,I2>::ManagedCPlusPlusArray(S2 size)
    {
        this->m_cppa = new CPlusPlusArray(size);
    }

    generic<typename S2, typename I2>
    void ManagedCPlusPlusArray<S2,I2>::SetItem(S2 index, I2 value)
    {
        this->m_cppa->SetItem(index, value); 
    }

    generic<typename S2, typename I2>
    I2 ManagedCPlusPlusArray<S2,I2>::GetItem(S2 index)
    {
        return this->m_cppa->GetItem(index);
    }

    generic<typename S2, typename I2>
    S2 ManagedCPlusPlusArray<S2,I2>::Size(void)
    {
        return this->m_cppa->Size();
    }

    generic<typename S2, typename I2>
    ManagedCPlusPlusArray<S2,I2>::~ManagedCPlusPlusArray(void)
    {
        delete this->m_cppa;
        this->m_cppa = NULL;
    }
}
```

**The C++ .dll:**

```
.h:
#ifndef __CPlusPlusArray_h__
#define __CPlusPlusArray_h__

//more about this in reference 1
#ifdef CPLUSPLUSARRAY_EXPORTS
   #define CPLUSPLUSARRAY_API  __declspec(dllexport)   // export DLL information

#else
   #define CPLUSPLUSARRAY_API  __declspec(dllimport)   // import DLL information

#endif 

template <typename I, typename S> class CPLUSPLUSARRAY_API CPlusPlusArray {
private:
    S _size;
    I _items[];
public:
    CPlusPlusArray(S size);
    void SetItem(S index, I value);
    I GetItem(S index);
    S Size(void);
    ~CPlusPlusArray(void);   
};

#endif

.cpp:
#include <iostream>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN     // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
#include <windows.h>

#include "CPlusPlusArray.h"


#ifdef _MANAGED
#pragma managed(push, off)
#endif

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(
    HMODULE     /*hModule*/,
    DWORD       ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID      /*lpReserved*/)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

#ifdef _MANAGED
#pragma managed(pop)
#endif

template <typename I, typename S>
CPlusPlusArray<I, S>::CPlusPlusArray(S size) 
{
    this->_size = size;
    this->_items = new I[this->_size];
}
template <typename I, typename S>
void CPlusPlusArray<I, S>::SetItem(S index, I value) 
{
    this->_items[index] = val;
}
template <typename I, typename S>
I CPlusPlusArray<I, S>::GetItem(S index)
{
    return this->_item[index];
}
template <typename I, typename S>
S CPlusPlusArray<I, S>::Size(void)
{
    return this->_size;
}
template <typename I, typename S>
CPlusPlusArray<I, S>::~CPlusPlusArray(void)
{
    delete[] this->_items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is at least two errors :

- you need to enclose your class definition in the cpp file in the same namespace as the class declaration
- you must specify generic argument list, as it is an integral part of the type

So this should give something like :

```
namespace ManagedCPlusPlusArray
{
    generic<typename S, typename I>
    ManagedCPlusPlusArray<S,I>::ManagedCPlusPlusArray(S size)
    {
        this->m_cppa = new CPlusPlusArray(size);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that has cleaned up a few errors. I am getting a few others, but think they are related: "error C3857: 'CPlusPlusArray': multiple template parameter lists are not allowed", "error C2989: 'CPlusPlusArray' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template", "error C2514: 'CPlusPlusArray' : class has no constructors." I've included the unmanaged C++ dll code, if that is of any help.